# Find all Func delegates

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, func

Why

```
var funcDelegatesCount = Assembly.Load("mscorlib")
        .GetTypes()
        .Count(t => 
               t.Name.StartsWith("Func`") 
            && t.BaseType == typeof(MulticastDelegate));
```

returns 9. But in fact there are 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh. The answer is funny.

- `Func<>` to `Func<,,,,,,,,>` are in `mscorlib` assembly.
- `Func<,,,,,,,,>` to `Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>` are in `System.Core` assembly.

Check:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} != {1}",
    typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,>).Assembly, typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,>).Assembly);
```